# How to read an array from a file and store it in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, file

I am trying to read an array from a file and save it in `myArray[]`.

File1.txt is `["abc", "def"...]` and I want to be able to parse `myArray[0]` which is "abc", `myArray[1]` which is "def" and so on.

```
f = File.open('file.text')
payload = f.read
puts payload
```

gives output as `["abc", "def"...]` which is a string and it becomes difficult to read as an array.

Comment: Please show your attempts

Comment: f = File.open('file.text')
payload = f.read
puts payload


gives output as  "["abc", "def"...]" which is a string and it becomes difficult to read as an array.

Comment: This could be done with a regular expression

Comment: Please do NOT put code in a comment. Edit your question and add the missing code as if you'd added it initially. Do not add "Edit:" or "Update:" to mark it as we can see when and where things have been changed. Also, please format your question correctly; Failing to do so only slows and discourages our responses. The more effort you put into your question to research, solve and ask it will pay off in the effort used to answer it. Read "[ask]", "[mcve]", http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users and http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Where does "File1.txt" come from? If it's `["abc", "def"..]` then it's not a standard serialized format and needs to be changed to a standard serialization, such as JSON or YAML, and whoever came up with the current format should be subject to a very pointed code-review. I suspect this is [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you should ask "How should I store data on disk", instead of "How do I read the data I've stored on disk?"

Comment: Hello @TinMan, I am writing into the file and creating it. What do you think is the best format for data like above? abc and def are actually xml strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `Kernel#eval` to parse the file contents (string) as Ruby code.

Contents of eval.txt:

```
['abc', 'def']
```

Ruby code:

```
contents = File.read("eval.txt")
foo = Kernel.eval(contents)
puts "Length of foo is #{foo.length}"
```

Outputs:

```
Length of foo is 2
```

Using JSON as your serialization format might be saner option though.

Comment: I think JSON is much saner. This seems like it could be dangerous. Actually, `exec` might be the dangerous one.

Comment: Hi @cody, thanks for your response and the solution you provided perfectly worked for me! Thanks again. Could you also elaborate on 'Using JSON as your serialization format might be saner option though?' I am not sure what you mean here. The content I am trying to read from the file is not a key value pair.

Comment: Nashita, it would not be surprising if the string contained in the file were produced with `JSON`: `require 'json'; JSON.generate ["abc", "def"] #=> "[\"abc\",\"def\"]"` (or `["abc", "def"].to_json`). You can convert the string back to the array with `JSON.parse "[\"abc\",\"def\"]" #=> ["abc", "def"]` (or `JSON.parse '["abc", "def"]' #=> ["abc", "def"]'`).  See the doc for the [JSON module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) and, for example, [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-rubys-json-library--cms-24771).